# symplectic Runge-Kutta for matrix differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, sg.symplectic-geometry, na.numerical-analysis

I would like to solve, for $t>0$ the following matrix differential equation:

$$U'(t)=H(t)U(t)$$

with initial condition $U(t=0)=U_0$ ($2N\times2N$, symplectic and unitary matrix) and $H(t=0)=H_0$ ($2N\times2N$, Hamiltonian and skew-Hermitian matrix). Both the matrices $H(t)$ and $U(t)$ are supposed to be smooth on the $t$ parameter.

I searched though the literature for some Runge-Kutta methods that preserve the symplectic structure of this problem and I could find few references dealing with this problem. However they do not provide details about the implementation such as, for example, the coefficients of the Runge-Kutta method.

Do you know any reference that could help me? Or, even better, can anyone directly help me with this problem?

Comment: Do you mean $U'(t) = H(t)U(t)$?

Comment: oh, sorry it is a typo. You are right.

Comment: I suspect that instead of using a piecewise-linear solution, you will want to use a piecewise-geodesic solution. If you replace H(t) by a piecewise-constant function, then the equation $U' = H(t)U$ will look something like $e^{H_0 t}$ in the first step, $e^{H_0t_0}e^{H_1(t-t_0)}$ in the next, etc.

Comment: Thanks Joshua for your answer, however it sounds a bit obscure to me: this is my fault, I do not know what a piecewise-geodesic solution is. Could you please elaborate a little bit more, or point me towards some reference?

Comment: This question isn't really in scope for MO, since the answer can be found in many textbooks.  The most complete reference on this topic is [the book of Hairer, Wanner, & Lubich](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-30666-8).

Comment: Thank you David for your answer. As you can see I am quite new on MO. Could you please point me to a page defining the scope for MO? I do not understand your comment "the question isn't in the scope of MO since the answer can be found in many textbooks"? My question was also about references: if I am asking, it is because I know nothing about the domain and maybe some expert can help.